# trouble accessing max of nested object data for use in a domain in D3

Tags: d3.js, multidimensional-array, nested, max

I have csv data with a column of years and then columns of age groups with rates:

```
year,15-19,20-24,25-29,...
1999,0,1.3,8.1,...
2000,0,1.3,8.3,...
.
.
```

I've mapped the data as shown below. Once mapped the data is in the form of:

```
>Array[Object, Object, ...]
```

Each Object is of the form:

```
 >id:"age group"
     values:Array[]
           >Object
               >rate: ""
               >year: ""
```

I'm having trouble with the max value for the y.domain. It seems to be pulling the max value from my 4th object and stopping there. Any help figuring out what's wrong with the max call would be appreciated.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// define scales
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    //define color scale
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

//define line generator
var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.rate); });

//load data
d3.csv("breaseByageSpread.csv", function(error, data) { 
    if(error) throw error;

        var ages = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {year: d.year, rate: d[id]};
                })
            };
        });


        //define x axis
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));

        //define y axis
        y.domain([
            d3.min(ages, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.rate; }); }),
            d3.max(ages, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.rate; }); })
        ]);


        // define color scale
        z.domain(ages.map(function(c) { return c.id; }));

        //append x axis
        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
            .ticks(15)
            .tickFormat(d3.format('d')));

        //append y axis
        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", -50)
                .attr('x', -125)
                .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                .attr("fill", "#000")
                .text("Rate per 100,000 ppl");

        //append rate data to svg
        var rate = g.selectAll(".rate")
            .data(ages)
            .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "age");

        //append rate path to svg
        rate.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });

          rate.append("text")
              .datum(function(d) { return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.year) + "," + y(d.value.rate) + ")"; })
              .attr("x", 3)
              .attr("dy", "0.35em")
              .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
              .text(function(d) { return d.id; });


        function type(d, _, columns) {
          //d.date = parseTime(d.date);
          for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
          return d;

        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The rates data was coming in as strings. To convert it to a numeric I changed the following code when loading the data:

Old:

```
values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {year: d.year, rate: d[id]};
```

New:

```
values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {year: d.year, rate: +d[id]};
```